# Is it possible to change the expiry threshold for expiring certificates in Exchange? (Event 12018)

Tags: exchange, exchange-2013, lets-encrypt

We've recently switched to using LetsEncrypt for our Exchange certificates, which have a maximum validity of 90 days.

Unfortunately this means I'm being pestered with tickets generated by our monitoring system due to Event 12018 occurring.

```
Application log generated Error Event 12018 on <myserver>

Log: Application
Type: Error
Event: 12018
Agent Time: 2018-05-18 00:00:30Z
Source: MSExchangeTransport
Category: TransportService
Username: N/A
Computer: <myserver>.local
Description: The STARTTLS certificate will expire soon: subject: CN=Let''s Encrypt Authority X3, O=Let''s Encrypt, C=USCN=<mydomain>, thumbprint: <certthumbprint>, hours remaining: 2159. Run the New-ExchangeCertificate cmdlet to create a new certificate.
```

2159 hours is 89.95 days.

Is it possible to change this threshold to something like 336 hours (2 weeks)?

Answer (score 0):

Never heard there is a way can change this threshold, it is by design, gives you enough time to get your change control logged and have the cert issued by the upstream provider.

Comment: The certificate is only valid for 90 days at the time of issue, and gets renewed automatically every 30 days.